# What is the recurrence relation for this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

> From the *Book Table of Integrals, Series and Products,* on page 9, equation 0.235 says:
> $$
> S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4k^2 - 1)^n},
> $$
> with the first few values
> $$
> S_1 = \frac{1}{2}, \quad 
> S_2 = \frac{\pi^2 - 8}{16}, \quad 
> S_3 = \frac{32 - 3\pi^2}{64}, \quad 
> S_4 = \frac{\pi^4 + 30\pi^2 - 384}{768} 
> $$

What is the general formula or recurrence relation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104860

Answer (score 1):

If you want to better understand, look at
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{(4k^2 - 1)^n}$$ and you will see terms in $x$, $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ and Lerch phi functions.

Now, making $x=1$ lead to the specific values. For example
$$S_{10}=$$ $$ \frac{-1486356480+68918850 \pi ^2+4729725 \pi ^4+270270 \pi ^6+8415 \pi
   ^8+62 \pi ^{10}}{2972712960}$$